# calculate distance from tap Point com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView

Tags: android, position, distance

I use `com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView` with the `OnDataPointTapListener` the method `onTap` gives the `DataPointInterface` dataPoint.

Is it possible to calculate the closed drawn `dataPoint` (Array)?

```
@Override
public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
    //find closed data point with Array DataPoint[] and the 
    //given DataPointInterface dataPoint
}
```

Can I maybe use the `radius`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. If you have the same question. Use this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eij1.png)